# Ignore package in colcon but not catkin?

Tags: ros2, catkin, ros-bouncy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

catkin ignores packages when they have COLCON_IGNORE in them. (https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/catkin_pkg/blob/35137d5522fc4b4140bf24d4d35373a1ff74e4e9/src/catkin_pkg/packages.py#L47)

I'd like to have ros1 and ros2 packages in parallel in two subdirectories of the same git repository and not get this error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package):
  By not providing "Findcatkin.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "catkin", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "catkin" with any
  of the following names:

    catkinConfig.cmake
    catkin-config.cmake
...
```

`--packages-skip` exists but has to be typed in every time there is a build, I don't see a blacklist option to add to a colcon config to ignore it for all following builds.

Building with catkin produces (more innocuous) warnings:

```
[build] Warning: Skipping package `foo2` because it has an unsupported package build type: `ament_cmake`
[build] Note: Available build types:                                                               
[build]  - `cmake`                                                                                 
[build]  - `catkin`
```

And then those can be eliminated with --blacklist.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/306624/ignore-package-in-colcon-but-not-catkin?/) by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 8729 on 2018-10-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

## mixins

```
sudo apt install python3-colcon-mixin
```

`src/my/mixins/skip.mixin`:

```
{
  "build": {
    "skip": {
      "packages-skip": ["foo1",
                        "foo2",
                        "bar",
                        ],
    }
  }
}
```

`src/my/mixins/index.yaml`:

```
mixin:
    - skip.mixin
```

Then:

```
colcon mixin add skip file://`pwd`/src/my/mixins/index.yaml
colcon mixin update skip
fetching links: file:///home/lucasw/ros2_ws/src/my/mixins/index.yaml ...
  fetching file:///home/lucasw/ros2_ws/src/my/mixins/skip.mixin ...
  * /home/lucasw/.colcon/mixin/skip/skip.mixin
```

And run update if the index or mixin file/s change, and build with

```
colcon build --mixin skip
```

More on colcon mixins: https://github.com/colcon/colcon-mixin-repository

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2018-11-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2018-11-02**:
Hopefully in the near future you won't need to create your own local `index.yaml` for this but can just pass `--mixin-file path/to/skip.mixin`...

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2018-11-03**:
The mixing doesn't provide persistence either and seems to be more effort than the options mentioned in the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The build tool is not a valid criteria for concluding if a build is for ROS 1 or ROS 2 (e.g. you can use `colcon` to build a ROS 1 workspace).

Generally it is not a workflow we recommend - to keep ROS 1 and ROS 2 packages on the same branch - so it will likely not be supported in all cases.

You could check the `ROS_VERSION` environment variable and make a decision about "skipping" a package in it's CMake logic. But as I said that is more like a hack and you might run into problems going down that path.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2018-10-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2018-10-24**:
Will there be a colcon --blacklist?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2018-10-24**:
There are already the options `--packages-ignore` (to skip packages during discovery, same as a `*_IGNORE` file) as well as `--packages-skip` and `--packages-skip-regex` (to deselect discovered packages).

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2018-10-24**:
But no persistence of those kinds of settings in a build.yaml/config.yaml as with catkin?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2018-10-24**:
At the moment there is no "profile" / "default mixin". You could create a mixin file manually to aggregate multiple command line options and select it explictly (`--mixin mymixin`) but that would still require to at least pass that argument - so not very convenient.

**Comment by [jrgnicho](https://answers.ros.org/users/22410/jrgnicho/) on 2020-01-13**:
There's an enhancement suggestion for this feature [here](https://github.com/colcon/colcon-mixin-repository)

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2020-01-13**:
@jrgnicho your link points to a repository which has no issues or pull requests open?

**Comment by [jrgnicho](https://answers.ros.org/users/22410/jrgnicho/) on 2020-02-19**:
@Dirk Thomas here is the link to that issue https://github.com/colcon/colcon-mixin/issues/18